# Limit and Function defined at a Point of Discontinutiy.

Tags: limits, continuity

Find the value of a that makes the following function continuous on $(-\infty, \infty)$. $f(x)= \frac{4x^3+13x^2+13x+30}{x+3}$  if  $x\lt-3$, $5x^2+3x+a$  if $x \ge -3$}?

Answer (score 0):

when x goes to from left -3 limit of f(x) = 43

there fore for the continuity when x goes to -3 right limit of 5x^2+3x+a must be equal to 43

thus 5*9+3*(-3)+ a = 43

a=7